# Get-ADGroupMember sort name and add a ';' behind each name

Tags: powershell

I want to get all user/groups which are member of a group sort by name. I can do this using following code:

```
Get-ADGroupMember ADGroup -Recursive | sort name | ft Name
```

I get something like this:

```
Smith, Michael

McCanning, Peter

Obama, Glen

Griffin, Kate
```

But I want to get this:

```
Smith, Michael;

McCanning, Peter;

Obama, Glen;

Griffin, Kate;
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Get-ADGroupMember ADGroup -Recursive | sort name | ForEach-Object { $_.name + ";" }
```

Comment: Great! that's it. Ok, I loose the headline ( ft Name )  but that is not important for me.

Comment: @rolfderwolf If you want the result to be an array of **objects** (so it keeps the 'headline'), don't use `ForEach-Object` but use `Select-Object` instead with a calculated property: `Get-ADGroupMember ADGroup -Recursive | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Name + ';'}}`